# Creating R function to check multiple conditions on multiple variables

Tags: r, function

I defined criteria to identify outliers in my dataframe (if the confidence interval (CI) does not overlap with the CI of my model)

I tried to create a function that checks my data frame is this was true for any case:

```
is.outlier <- function(cilbr, ciubr, cilb.model, ciub.model) {
  for (x in 1:length(cilbr)) {
  if (cilbr > ciub.model || ciubr < cilb.model) {
    print(TRUE)
  }
    else {
      print(FALSE)
    }
      }
}
```

cilbr = lower boundary of data CI, ciubr = upper boundary of data CI

When I now apply it to my dataframe, "FALSE" is returned for all rows (besides some rows definitely being a outliers):

```
ma1$outlier <- is.outlier(ma1$cilbr, ma1$ciubr, 0.2484, 0.4195)

[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
...
```

Apparently it only takes the first case of my data and not all values

Any suggestions how I can fix this?

Example data:

```
   author   year     n     r   r_var   cilbr ciubr
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 Baker    2011    84 0.171 0.0114  -0.0451 0.372
2 Schmidt  2020   182 0.32  0.00445  0.183  0.445
3 Meyer    2010   250 0.096 0.00394 -0.0284 0.217
4 Miller   1990    25 0.28  0.0354  -0.129  0.608
```

Comment: Some example data would help